# Boxplot colour mismatch

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to color the dots of the plot with the legend Episode values. What I am missing?

[image]

I replaced `fill` with `color` still is not the plot that I would like to have

[image]

Sample code:

```
(p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Type, y=Value, fill=Episode, group=Type)) + 
    
    geom_boxplot()+
    geom_line()+
    geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', 
                 position=position_dodge(0.8))+
    theme_bw())
```

Sample data:

```
 df<-structure(list(Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), 
        Episode = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"
        ), class = "factor"), Value = c(32, 36, 57, 83, 88, 40, 40, 
        44, 67, 77, 66, 45, 88, 46, 56, 99, 65, 0, 66, 46, 59, 77, 
        74, 79, 38, 45, 60, 78, 66, 75, 45, 55, 68, 77, 88, 35, 36, 
        118, 80, 73, 71, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For points, use `color=`, not `fill=`

Comment: why do you have a line through the middle of the boxplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand your question correctly, but for me, the cleanest plot would be:

```
library(ggplot2)
df<-structure(list(Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                      4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
                                      7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), 
                   Episode = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                         4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                         4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6"
                                         ), class = "factor"), Value = c(32, 36, 57, 83, 88, 40, 40, 
                                                                         44, 67, 77, 66, 45, 88, 46, 56, 99, 65, 0, 66, 46, 59, 77, 
                                                                         74, 79, 38, 45, 60, 78, 66, 75, 45, 55, 68, 77, 88, 35, 36, 
                                                                         118, 80, 73, 71, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Type, y=Value, group = Type)) +  
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(col=Episode))
p
```

[image]

Created on 2021-04-15 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)